# How to create Image Shadow on Android?

Tags: react-native

I try to shadow image like on ios but i can't. I use  `elevation` but nothing change and i get warning `Invalid props.style key 'evelation'`. How can i show image on Android like ios?

[ss-ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxkCP.png)

[ss-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwjxJ.png)

[ss-warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ukWN.png)

My style:

```
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOffset: {width: 0, height:  2 },
shadowOpacity:  0.5,
shadowRadius: 3,
elevation: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, the warning is telling you that you wrote `evelation` even if the code you posted is fine, are you sure they are the same?

Comment: i am getting this warning for image. if i dont use evelation for image there isnt any problem, but i want shadow image for android

Answer (score 0):

try giving it a platform specific

```
import{Platform} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
image: {
..Platform.select({
     ios: {
       shadowColor: 'black',
       shadowOffset: {width: 0, height:  2 },
       shadowOpacity:  0.5,
       shadowRadius: 3,
     },
     android: {
       elevation: 4
     },
    }),
  }
})
```

Comment: what about giving the image a `View`, and `shadow` to the `View` : `<View style={styles.image}><Image /> </View>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shadow generator.

https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

You will have to define the shadow on top view component and give the same width and height on both view and image component.

Example

```
    <View
      style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 12,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.58,
        shadowRadius: 16.0,
        elevation: 24,
      }}>
      <Image
        source={DemoImage}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Thanks but i cant use it for image

Comment: Please check the answer i have added example.

Comment: when i use it in view it the shadow will square but i want a just shadow of png image